# Why are Next.js' req.query object's values of type string | string[]?

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

Next.js' API Routes receive a `req` object - it's an extension of [http.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) with [additional middlewares](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares) such as `req.query`. The typing of `req.query`, found in their [utils.ts](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/ef32e16fb1e65e0b8278a295cc584bbc696ae6f4/packages/next/next-server/lib/utils.ts#L203), is:

```js
query: {
    [key: string]: string | string[]
}
```

Why is it possible to receive an array of strings from the query?

I'm trying to perform string methods on my query values but run into TS errors -_-

```js
someString.split() // => Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
```

Comment: Because you can have e.g. `?foo=bar&foo=baz`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh snap! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think we can use this, if we don't work with more than one param with the same name:

```
const id = req.query.id as string
```

Comment: This does not ensure `req.query.id` is a string, and can still lead to run time errors. You should use a type guard like `typeof req.query.id === 'string'` to narrow down its type before executing operations on it.

Answer (score 3):

the query object is of type string | string[] because of catch all routes
https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

if you had a file that was named [id].js and used the url pages/123, router.query would return a string 123, but if the file was named [...id].js and used the url pages/123 it would be a catch all route and would return an array ["123"], if the url were pages/123/456 it would return ["123", "456"]

Answer (score 2):

You can convert 'string | string[]' to 'string' by joining them like this:

```
let { param } = req.query.param;
if (Array.isArray(param)) {
  param = param.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the solutions suggested above but with support for multiple params

```
const { param1, param2 } = req.query as { param1: string; param2: string };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Bruno mentioned. If we know that our page is [id].tsx, I think it's safe to use type assertion.

```
const id = req.query.id as string
```

I'm not really sure if explicit type narrowing is needed in this case as routing to this page is ensured to contain id as string by nextjs. Is there really a chance that this type assertion can go wrong?